# Simple proof of special case of Clark-Ocone formula?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I've seen the usual proof of the Clark-Ocone formula in the context of Malliavin calculus, but I'm wondering whether anyone knows or can think of a simple proof of the statement

$$
B_t^n = E[B_t^n] + \int_0^t E[nB_t^{n-1}\mid\mathcal{F}_s]\,\mathrm dB_s.
$$

Working it out even for $n=2,3$ is I think a nice exercise for students in an introductory sotchastic calculus class, but I wonder if there is a relatively easy way to deduce this formula, one that would also be appropriate for students.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\R{\mathbb{R}}\def\N{\mathbb{N}}\def\d{\mathrm{d}}\def\F{\mathscr{F}}\def\ev{\biggr|}\def\peq{\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{}}$Here is a proof using Ito's formula. Consider a fixed $T > 0$.

> **Step 1:** For $t \in [0, T)$,\begin{gather*}
> E(B_T^n \mid \F_t) = \sum_{m = 0}^n \binom{n}{m} E((B_T - B_t)^m) B_t^{n - m} = \sum_{m = 0}^{\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right]} a_m (T - t)^m B_t^{n - 2m},\tag{1.1}
> \end{gather*}
>   where $a_m = \dbinom{n}{2m} (2m - 1)!!$ satisfies\begin{gather*}
> a_0 = 1,\ a_{m + 1} = \frac{(n - 2m)(n - 2m - 1)}{2(m + 1)} a_m \left( 0 \leqslant m < \left[ \frac{n}{2} \right] \right).\tag{1.2}
> \end{gather*}

*Proof:* Because $σ(B_T - B_t)$ and $\F_t$ are independent and $B_t$ is $\F_t$-measurable, so\begin{align*}
&\peq E(B_T^n \mid \F_t) = E((B_T - B_t + B_t)^n \mid \F_t)\\
&= E\left( \sum_{m = 0}^n \binom{n}{m} (B_T - B_t)^m B_t^{n - m} \,\middle|\, \F_t \right) = \sum_{m = 0}^n \binom{n}{m} E((B_T - B_t)^m B_t^{n - m} \mid \F_t)\\
&= \sum_{m = 0}^n \binom{n}{m} B_t^{n - m} E((B_T - B_t)^m \mid \F_t) = \sum_{m = 0}^n \binom{n}{m} B_t^{n - m} E((B_T - B_t)^m).
\end{align*}
By Stein's lemma, $E((B_T - B_t)^m) = (m - 1)(T - t) E((B_T - B_t)^{m - 2})$, thus induction shows that $E((B_T - B_t)^{2m - 1}) = 0$ and (1.2) follows.

> **Step 2:** For $k \in \N_+$ and $l \in \N$,\begin{gather*}
> \int_0^T B_t^l \,\d B_t = \frac{B_T^{l + 1}}{l + 1} - \int_0^T \frac{l}{2} B_t^{l - 1} \,\d t,\\
> \int_0^T (T - t)^k B_t^l \,\d B_t = \int_0^T \left( \frac{k}{l + 1} (T - t)^{k - 1} B_t^{l + 1} - \frac{l}{2} (T - t)^k B_t^{l - 1} \right) \,\d t.\tag{2.1}
> \end{gather*}

*Proof:* By Ito's formula,$$
\d(B_t^{l + 1}) = (l + 1) B_t^l \,\d B_t + \frac{1}{2} l(l + 1) B_t^{l - 1} \,\d t,
$$
thus$$
\int_0^T B_t^l \,\d B_t = \frac{B_t^{l + 1}}{l + 1} \ev_0^T - \int_0^T \frac{l}{2} B_t^{l - 1} \,\d t = \frac{B_T^{l + 1}}{l + 1} - \int_0^T \frac{l}{2} B_t^{l - 1} \,\d t.
$$
Also by Ito's formula,\begin{align*}
\d((T - t)^k B_t^{l + 1}) &= -k(T - t)^{k - 1} B_t^{l + 1} \,\d t + (l + 1) (T - t)^k B_t^l \,\d B_t\\
&\peq + \frac{1}{2} l(l + 1) (T - t)^k B_t^{l - 1} \,\d t,
\end{align*}
thus\begin{gather*}
{\small \int_0^T (T - t)^k B_t^l \,\d B_t = \frac{1}{l + 1} (T - t)^k B_t^{l + 1} \ev_0^T + \int_0^T \frac{k}{l + 1} (T - t)^{k - 1} B_t^{l + 1} \,\d t - \int_0^T \frac{l}{2} (T - t)^k B_t^{l - 1} \,\d t}\\
= \int_0^T \left( \frac{k}{l + 1} (T - t)^{k - 1} B_t^{l + 1} - \frac{l}{2} (T - t)^k B_t^{l - 1} \right) \,\d t.
\end{gather*}

> **Step 3:**$$
> \int_0^T E(B_T^n \mid \F_t) \,\d B_t = \frac{1}{n + 1} (B_T^{n + 1} - E(B_T^{n + 1})).
> $$

*Proof:* By (1.1) and (2.1),\begin{align*}
&\peq \int_0^T E(B_T^n \mid \F_t) \,\d B_t = \int_0^T \sum_{m = 0}^{\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right]} a_m (T - t)^m B_t^{n - 2m} \,\d B_t = \sum_{m = 0}^{\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right]} a_m \int_0^T (T - t)^m B_t^{n - 2m} \,\d B_t\\
&= \sum_{m = 1}^{\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right]} a_m \int_0^T \left( \frac{m}{n - 2m + 1} (T - t)^{m - 1} B_t^{n - 2m + 1} - \frac{n - 2m}{2} (T - t)^m B_t^{n - 2m - 1} \right) \,\d t\\
&\peq + \left( \frac{B_T^{n + 1}}{n + 1} - \int_0^T \frac{n}{2} B_t^{n - 1} \,\d t \right)\\
&= {\small \int_0^T \Biggl( \sum_{m = 1}^{\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right]} a_m · \frac{m}{n - 2m + 1} (T - t)^{m - 1} B_t^{n - 2m + 1} - \sum_{m = 1}^{\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right]} a_m · \frac{n - 2m}{2} (T - t)^m B_t^{n - 2m - 1} - \frac{n}{2} B_t^{n - 1} \Biggr) \,\d t}\\
&\peq + \frac{B_T^{n + 1}}{n + 1}.\tag{3}
\end{align*}
Note that\begin{align*}
&\peq {\small \sum_{m = 1}^{\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right]} a_m · \frac{m}{n - 2m + 1} (T - t)^{m - 1} B_t^{n - 2m + 1} - \sum_{m = 1}^{\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right]} a_m · \frac{n - 2m}{2} (T - t)^m B_t^{n - 2m - 1} - \frac{n}{2} B_t^{n - 1} }\\
&= \Biggl( \frac{a_1}{n - 1} B_t^{n - 1} + \sum_{m = 1}^{\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right] - 1} a_{m + 1} · \frac{m + 1}{n - 2m - 1} (T - t)^m B_t^{n - 2m - 1} \Biggr)\\
&\peq - \Biggl( \sum_{m = 1}^{\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right]} a_m · \frac{n - 2m}{2} (T - t)^m B_t^{n - 2m - 1} \Biggr) - \frac{n}{2} a_0 B_t^{n - 1}\\
&= \left( \frac{a_1}{n - 1} - \frac{n}{2} a_0 \right) B_t^{n - 1} + \sum_{m = 1}^{\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right] - 1} \left( a_{m + 1} · \frac{m + 1}{n - 2m - 1} - a_m · \frac{n - 2m}{2} \right) (T - t)^m B_t^{n - 2m - 1}\\
&\peq - a_{\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right]} · \frac{n - 2\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right]}{2} (T - t)^{\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right]} B_t^{n - 2\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right] - 1}\\
&\stackrel{(1.2)}{=} -a_{\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right]} · \frac{n - 2\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right]}{2} (T - t)^{\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right]} B_t^{n - 2\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right] - 1} = \begin{cases}
-\dfrac{1}{2} a_{\frac{n - 1}{2}} (T - t)^{\frac{n - 1}{2}}; & n \text{ is odd}\\
0; & n \text{ is even}
\end{cases}.
\end{align*}
Thus for odd $n$,\begin{gather*}
(3) = \frac{B_T^{n + 1}}{n + 1} - \frac{1}{2} a_{\frac{n - 1}{2}} \int_0^T (T - t)^{\frac{n - 1}{2}} \,\d t = \frac{B_T^{n + 1}}{n + 1} - \frac{1}{2} a_{\frac{n - 1}{2}} · \frac{2}{n + 1} T^{\frac{n + 1}{2}}\\
\stackrel{(1.2)}{=} \frac{B_T^{n + 1}}{n + 1} - \frac{n!!}{n + 1} T^{\frac{n + 1}{2}} = \frac{B_T^{n + 1}}{n + 1} - \frac{E(B_T^{n + 1})}{n + 1}.
\end{gather*}
For even $n$,$$
(3) = \frac{B_T^{n + 1}}{n + 1} = \frac{B_T^{n + 1}}{n + 1} - \frac{E(B_T^{n + 1})}{n + 1}.
$$

Comment: Wow, thanks! I have to say, though, this is not so simple. I'll give you the bounty, but I want to leave it open a bit longer, in case anyone has an easier way. Thanks, though.

Comment: @GregMarkowsky This proof is indeed a bit complicated :/ I guess Malliavin calculus has effectively swept a lot of details under the carpet through out the construction of its theory.

Comment: Thanks. Complicated or not, you got it, and the bounty is yours. I appreciate the effort.

Comment: Saad, if you're ever interested in earning a bounty that might get your name on a paper, please send me an email.

Comment: @GregMarkowsky Thanks for the offer. I'd be glad to get bounties whenever I'm able to, but for the paper part… I'm afraid that my contribution would be too miniscule to be useful for any paper, so thanks.

Comment: Nonsense. Someone who can do difficult stochastic calculus manipulations is always valuable as a member of a research team, at least the kind of research I do. I don't know what your career situation is, whether you care about getting publications, but if you do then you should send me your contact details.